# Adding Custom META tag to XML file

Tags: java, xml

I created a java application that generates a whole bunch of simple XML files using the DocumentBuilder class. But now I need to go back and modify it so that all of the XML files also include this meta tag inserted before the root 'resultset' element:

```
<meta name="ZOOMPAGEBOOST" content="5">
```

So that the resulting files will look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="..\..\..\stylesheet\mysql-result.xsl"?>
<meta name="ZOOMPAGEBOOST" content="5">
<resultset>
    <row>
    ...
    </row>
</resultset>
```

Is this possible using the DocumentBuilder class? I figured this would have been a simple change, but I am having a difficult time finding the solution.

Comment: As an alternative you could switch to a zip-based file format and store the meta data xml alongside the data xml in the zip file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to build is **not** well formed XML, DocumentBuilder won't let you build it because of that reason. Not to mention that the `meta` element you use in your example isn't valid XML either because it isn't closed; you have multiple problems here.

You have to have a single root element, the following **is** valid XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="..\..\..\stylesheet\mysql-result.xsl"?>
<resultset>
<meta name="ZOOMPAGEBOOST" content="5"/>
    <row>
    ...
    </row>
</resultset>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to get it to work using the valid XML you posted above.